# segmentation error in for loop in c

Tags: c, for-loop, segmentation-fault, scanf, ram

I have a text file that contains numbers arranged like:

```
0.200   1.3300   1.2555
0.201   1.3300   1.2620
0.202   1.3300   1.2685
0.203   1.3300   1.2751
0.204   1.3248   1.2817
.
.
.
.
0.899   0.17380   5.7153
0.900   0.17435   5.7227
```

There is 700 line in this text file.I have written a C program that will read the line number from another text file named "fc.txt" and then will save three different numbers of that particular line into three different text files. The program is:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int l, i = 0, j;
    float a[100][100];
    float *p;
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("fc.txt", "r");
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &l);
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("Au.txt", "r");
    for (i = 0; i <= l; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
        {
            fscanf(fp, "%f", &a[i][j]);
            if (i == l)
            {
                p = &a[i][j];
                p++;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("i_ri.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "%f", *(p - 1));
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("r_ri.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "%f", *(p - 2));
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("w.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fp, "%f", *(p - 3));
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

When the line number written in "fc.txt" in 90 program is running with no problem. But when the line number is 100, a message is showing

****"*** stack smashing detected ***: **./ri terminated
Aborted (core dumped)"******

After line 120 it is showing that:

**Segmentation fault (core dumped)**

But I need to run this program for 700 lines. Please suggest some wayout to solve this problem.

Comment: Could you indent properly your code? You read only 6 values .... File opening is ok?

Comment: You want to write 700 elements into an array of 100 elements. How can that fit?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show the first 2-3 lines you expect of each of the output file. Also make clear which is the name of the file cintaining the 700 lines

Comment: `float a[100][100];` ==> `float a[700][3];`

Comment: What is your purpose?

Comment: The problem is solved. That was my mistake that I have initialized an array of 100 elements and then was trying to save beyond the limit. Thank you very much @mch to point out this silly mistake.

Comment: You really should not store the lines you don't need. And you only read and use 3 values into an array of 100. Huge waste of memory and slower overall.

Comment: well, you have dimensioned your array with only 100 rows, values of row larger than 99 will cause you to access memory outside your array, overwritting what could be there, and that's the reason of the Undefined Behaviour you are experimenting.

Answer (score 1):

I can not understand your purpose. I guess you want to read the data at specific line.

Demo without test:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *src;
    int nr;
    int i;
    float a[3];
    FILE *fp;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("Usage: %s <file> <line_number>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    src = argv[1];
    nr = atoi(argv[2]);

    if ((fp = fopen(src, "r")) == NULL)
    {
        printf("Fail to open file %s\n", src);
        return -1;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < nr; i++)
    {
        if (fscanf(fp, "%f %f %f", a, a + 1, a + 2) != 3)
        {
            printf("Unknown format\n");
            return -1;
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    // Now float arrays at line nr is stored at a[]
    printf("Your expected float array: \n");
    printf("[1] %f\n[2] %f\n[3] %f\n", a[0], a[1], a[2]);

    // Do your own job with a[]

    return 0;
}
```